# current_user.model via foreign key in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I feel like I am losing my mind, but can someone please restore it by answering this question. I am using Devise and have a current_user instance.  I also have an Identity model which has the following:

```
    t.references :user
    t.string :provider
    t.string :uid
    t.string :token
    t.string :secret_key
    t.string :nickname
    t.string :image
```

The relationships as follows:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Associations
    belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Associations
    has_many :identities
```

I am trying to get the "nickname" field from the Identity model via the current_user.

Why doesn't something like this work in the view?

`<%= current_user.identity.nickname %>`

I might add I am trying to do this within the appplication.html.erb template. I currently have no instance variables or anything setup for identity.

Thanks.

Comment: The User has many identities... current_user.identities.first.nickname ?

Comment: Not stupid, maybe tired ;) The problem is sitting most often just in front of the hardware :D Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A `user` has many identities so calling `user.identity` is somewhat wrong.  I'm assuming that you use the `identity` model to allow users to login via different services.  If this is the case, you should save the `identity` used by the user to log in in the session and just add a convenience method to get the current identity.

In the sessions controller create action, add the following code (this assumes that you know the `identity` record that the user used for logging in)

```
session[:identity_id] = identity.id
```

Then just add a controller and helper method called `current_identity`

```
def current_identity
  @current_identity ||= current_user.identities.find(session[:identity_id])
end
```

So in your application layout, just call `current_identity.nickname`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and this is a good suggestion, but is a bit overkill for me.